# Why doesn't [checked] work as selector in JQUERY?

Tags: jquery

It seems that the only way to select a checkable input that is actually checked is to use the :checked selector.

Is there a technical reason why this does not work:

```
$("INPUT[checked]")
```

whereas it seems to work for other attributes?

Comment: My guess is to retain the [css selector abiltiies](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-checked) it uses. But using an attribute in the selector should also work.

Comment: why it doesn't work? http://jsfiddle.net/QCCS3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"input[checked]"` will select based on the original HTML source code. Only those INPUT elements which are based on an HTML tag which contained a `checked` attribute will be selected.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/PXudH/

In my demo, the second check-box ("B") will be selected at all times, no matter how you check / uncheck the two check-boxes.

Answer (score 5):

Because you would need to put the value for an attribute.  But what is it?  You write in XHTML `checked="checked"`, in HTML4/5 just plain `checked`.  The DOM model should store it as true.

```
$('input[checked="checked"]'); // Poor
$('input[checked=true]'); // Maybe
```

But it is fiddly because of potential browser differences, and checking a boolean, so there is a specific way to do it.

```
$('input:checked'); // Correct
```

The internal implementation just checks the elements `.checked` attribute.

From [v1.5.1](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.js):

```
filters: {

    // ...

    checked: function( elem ) {
        return elem.checked === true;
    },

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("input:checked")` is the correct syntax.

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: The OP seems to known this, and is asking _why_.

Answer (score 1):

input[checked] says look for an attribute that 'might' be there, and it may even be unchecked, depending on the html.  input[checked] requires the generated HTML to already have the 'checked' attribute, which i think you knew.  Depending on how the `<input type="checkbox"/>` was generated, that may or not be true until the user clicks on the input.  Even after the click, what the attribute key value pair html looks like is browser finnicky.

Answer (score 0):

I think the technical reason may be that jQuery's selectors are case-sensitive.  This would work for all upper-case INPUT tags

Answer (score 0):

XHTML requires the `checked` attribute with `="checked"` after it, but some people don't write valid XHTML. Makes it simpler having only one expression for it.

Comment: Wrote that without even thinking, I meant XHTML requires the ="checked" but people don't always put it in

Comment: Yes, but XHTML validity is irrelevant. Every browser understands this `<input type="checkbox" checked>` regardless of whether or not the page is an HTML or XHTML document.

Comment: Yes but because it can be written in two ways, to check if an item is checked you would need two selectors, one for just the attribute and one for the attribute and the equality

Comment: I don't think two selectors are needed. This selector: `input[checked]` selects both `<input checked>` and `<input checked="checked">`.